# Can a block in Smalltalk be run by itself?

Tags: smalltalk

I know blocks can be passed and used in that way.

But is there any way to call a block, just by having a block? Something like this?

```
aBlock := [ ... ].
aBlock run.
```

I tried searching for the BlockClosure class in the System browser, but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes! And in fact, you can do pretty interesting things with them, like activating them within themselves. For example, this block computes factorial recursively calling itself:

```
factorialBlock := [:n | 
    n <= 1 
        ifTrue: [n]
        ifFalse: [n * (factorialBlock value: n - 1)]
]
```

and to try it:

```
factorialBlock value: 5
```

That would not be an example of a very good coding practice, but it is of the power of block closures!

Comment: Why that would not be good coding practice? We see people often advicing for recursion instead of iteration.

Answer (score 5):

Let's add that besides `value`, if your block has arguments, you can also use

```
[:f | <do something with f>] value: a
```

where `f` is a *formal* argument (an unbound variable name) and `a` is an *actual* object that will bind to `f` when `#value:` is sent.

For two arguments use `value:value:` and for many `valueWithArguments:`, which receives an `Array`.

---

**Examples**

```
[:x | x squared - 1] value: 3
                               ->  3 squared - 1 (i.e., 8)

[:x :y | x + 2 / (y - 4)] value: 2 value: 0
                               ->  2 + 2 / (0 - 4) (i.e., -1)
```

**Exercise**

What's the result of evaluating the following?:

```
block := [:x | x value: 2].
block value: [:y | y + 1]
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes it can. Also, you send the message 'value' to it to evaluate the block, not 'run'. In fact, you do not have to assign it to a variable. You can just do this:

```
[ ... ] value.
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this one:

Lambda Calculus in Pharo
Yes, the Y Combinator is useful in normal programs

https://medium.com/concerning-pharo/lambda-calculus-in-pharo-a4a571869594#.2a78xp31s

From the article:

```
  ycombinator := [ :f | 
  [ :g | g value: g ] value: [ :g |
    f value: [ :x | 
      (g value: g) value: x ] ] ]
```

The force is strong in this one.